# jQuery change event handler with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox and when it is enabled(checked), I want code to execute. It works but when the box is unchecked, the code still works, I would prefer it not work when the box is unchecked. The following code is within a larger jQuery function that works. I just can't get the code to stop working when I uncheck the box. For reference, the check box allows the user to use arrow keys to adjust a canvas element. I want them to be able to adjust when the box is checekd and not be able to adjust when it is unchecked.

```
$("#hMove728").click( function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert("checked");

    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
            switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
                case 38:
                    context.yB -= 2;
                break;
                    case 39:
                    x += 2;
            break;
            case 40:
                y += 2;
            break;
            case 37:
                x -= 2;
            break;
            default:
            break;
       }
     update();

    })
   }

});
```

Comment: An event handler inside another event handler seems to be a really bad idea, at least in this case.

Comment: How can I fix? This seems like it should be a simple fix, extra event handler or not. Right?

Comment: See the answer by @Cuberto , that has the general principle, just check it the checkbox is checked withing the keydown event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, check the state of the checkbox inside the event handler:

```
var moveCheckbox = $("#hMove728");
$( document ).keydown( function( key ) {
  if ( moveCheckbox.is(":checked") ) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: THanks! this works. I don't quite understand why, but at least it works.

Comment: It works because the state of the checkbox is checked every time the key is pressed. In your original, you were adding the keydown event handler to the `document` every time you would click on the checkbox - which is probably a bad idea - it's better to avoid defining event handlers within another event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('input').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            // It is checked
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to "unregister" the "keydown" event on your document when you remove the check, or you can make the check inside your keydown function. Like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if(!$("#hMove728").is(':checked')) return;
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        case 38:
            context.yB -= 2;
        break;
            case 39:
            x += 2;
        break;
        case 40:
            y += 2;
        break;
        case 37:
            x -= 2;
        break;
        default:
        break;
   }
   update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in else put the: 
$(document).unbind('keydown');

that will unbind the event with the name of keydown on document element.